# Tzitzis In the Bathroom

Tags: tzitzis, bathroom

Are you allowed to make Tzitzis In the Bathroom?

Comment: Tangentially, I heard that [RShZ"A](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shlomo_Zalman_Auerbach) finds it difficult to understand why the halakha permits a person to walk into a bathroom wearing tsitsit. This is b/c complete kavana is necessary when wearing tsitsit, and it is forbidden to think about torah umitsvot when in the bathroom.

Comment: Why do you think this might be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SHU"T Halachos Katanos that it is Muttar and he brings a Proof from Schitah that is done in a slaughterhouse which is a place that includes all the smells of the Bathroom and more,and another proof is he says you wear them in the Bathroom so he says while not optimal it is allowed. But the Mishnah Berurah says L'halacha by Shofar in the Name of the MATTEH EFRAIM that if you are in the bathroom and you want to have in mind to be Yotzeh the Mitzvah of Shofar it does not work.He quotes 2 reasons there :1-That Mitzvas need Kavanah to be Yotzeh you need to have in mind that Hashem wants you to do the Mitzvah and that is like learning in the Bathroom which is not allowed.2- It is the action of a mitzvah which is not allowed to be done In a way that is Unbecoming for a Mitzvah.so for the Tzitzis there is a yes if we can apply the Heter all across to all mitzvos it would seem NOT.

Comment: The answer was definitre suprise to me so I uped it it seems I end up doing it alot to answers why do they only allow so little everytime I reach My Limit?!

Comment: I uped it too defnitly not an everyday question